# Extension Method not compiling (No defintion for type 'string')

Tags: c#, linq, itemssource

I'm trying to convert bytes into KB/MB/GB using the code below, however, I can't seem to get it working. The value of quota, is 60000000000.

```
    public static double BytesToKilobytes(this Int32 bytes)
    {
        return bytes / 1000d;
    }

    public static double BytesToMegabytes(this Int32 bytes)
    {
        return bytes / 1000d / 1000d;
    }

    public static double BytesToGigabytes(this Int32 bytes)
    {
        return bytes / 1000d / 1000d / 1000d;
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        listBox1.ItemsSource = from query in xDocument.Descendants("service")
                               select new Service
                               {
                                   type = query.Attribute("type").Value,
                                   id = query.Element("id").Value,
                                   plan = query.Element("username").Value,
                                   quota = query.Element("quota").Value.BytesToGigabytes,                                   };
    }
```

The error the above code produces is:

"'string' does not contain a definition for 'BytesToGigabytes' and no extension method 'BytesToGigabytes' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Probably not your problem, but if the value of quota is 60*10^9, it won't fit into an Int32. You need to use a Int64 (aka long) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the quota is a string, you have to parse it into a number first:

```
quota = Decimal.Parse(query.Element("quota").Value).BytesToGigabytes()
```

As the number is too large to fit in a 32 bit integer, you have to use a Decimal:

```
public static Decimal BytesToGigabytes(this Decimal bytes) {
  return bytes / 1000m / 1000m / 1000m;
}
```

It would also be possible to use an Int64, but then the method would truncate the result, returning for example 3 GB instead of 3.9 GB.

Comment: Hi Guffa, I tried your solution however it threw the following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'".

Comment: @cvandal: Is `quota` a string member? Then you have to format the value into a string before assigning it.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that :) Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Value` is a string, while the extension methods are declared for `Int32`. You will need to convert the `Value` to an `Int32` prior to invoking the extension method.

Example:

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Func<string, Int64> convertToInt64 = s =>
    {
       Int64 result;
            // replace 0 with whatever default you want
       return Int64.TryParse(s, out result) ? result : 0;
    };
    if (e.Error != null) return; 
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(e.Result); 
    listBox1.ItemsSource = from query in xDocument.Descendants("service") 
                           select new Service 
                           { 
                               type = query.Attribute("type").Value, 
                               id = query.Element("id").Value, 
                               plan = query.Element("username").Value, 
                               quota = convertToInt64(query.Element("quota").Value)
                                           .BytesToKilobytes()
                           };
}
```

This also means that the extension methods should be declared for `Int64`:

```
public static double BytesToKilobytes(this Int64 bytes)
```

Comment: That is not possible. The value is too large to fit in an `Int32`.

Comment: @Guffa: true, should be `Int64`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing whats in your event args, the error is fairly straightforward.

There is no extension for a BytesToGigabytes for a type of string.

So query.Element("quota") is returning a string.  If you parse it (`int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` then you should have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of errors though .. u should divide by 1024 instead ... and convert value to Int .. see below.

```
 public static double BytesToKilobytes(this Int32 bytes)
    {
        return bytes / 1024d;
    }

    public static double BytesToMegabytes(this Int32 bytes)
    {
        return bytes / 1024d / 1024d;
    }

    public static double BytesToGigabytes(this Int32 bytes)
    {
        return bytes / 1024d / 1024d / 1024d;
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        listBox1.ItemsSource = from query in xDocument.Descendants("service")
                               select new Service
                               {
                                   type = query.Attribute("type").Value,
                                   id = query.Element("id").Value,
                                   plan = query.Element("username").Value,
                                   quota = Convert.ToInt32(query.Element("quota").Value).BytesToGigabytes(),                                   };
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: A kilobyte is 1000 bytes, what you are talking about is a kibibyte. It's possible that the OP actually wants kibibytes instead of kilobytes, but it's far from certain. The unit kilobyte is commonly used for both units.

Comment: @Guffa ... i affirm my love for SO ... i NEVER knew of the kibibyte till u mentioned it ... learning never ends ...